# BackTrack 5 gui won't load after Installation

Tags: gui, backtrack

I Have installed BackTrack 5. It works fine on a live bootable USB, but once I installed a gui it is not loading.

Using the command shell, it works fine, but when I type `startx` in root login, a black screen appears which remains forever.

I have tried many things, such as creating non-root users, then `startx`, but it doesn't help.

My laptop is a Lenovo G650. I have assigned 29GB to BackTrack with 4GB swap. 
I have an Intel Core2duo processor with integrated card and 3GB ram.

Comment: BackTrack is also a Live CD, isn't it? Does the X server starts when running on the CD / DVD ?
Also, please provide the log and output of Xserver.

Comment: Provide your /var/log/Xorg.log first

Answer (score 1):

When GRUB starts, press <kbd>e</kbd> on your keyboard and go straight to the `vga=791` line and add `i915.modeset=1`. Then press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to continue and you are good to go... but remember you have to doo this each time you restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a permanent solution than provide before, try following the next tuto, it works beautifuly for me:

http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=48904

The problem is that the kernel loads other graphics drivers insted of intel drivers, that's the reason you cannot start the X control, in the tutorial explain step by step what to do and before you mess with the kernel, it says how to check if the solution will work for you.

Hope it works.