# BackTrack 5 R3 programs aren't opening

Tags: livecd, backtrack

I'm running BackTrack 5 R3 on an old Dell Inspiron 700m using a LiveDVD. I'm running the Gnome 32 bit version. To make X start I had to use the solution [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35197/backtrack-5-gui-wont-load-after-installation) Once I get X open, I can't seem to open programs. When I click on Applications and then choose an application the cursor turns into a watch and the bottom panel says "Starting " program-Name-Here (Starting gedit). After about fifteen seconds the watch cursor and starting message go away without any program opening. How do I configure BackTrack to be able to open programs?

EDIT: I am unable to open the terminal.

EDIT 2 and 3: I'm not sure what I did, but after a reboot or two programs are opening properly!

Comment: What happens if you run programs from the terminal?

Comment: I can't open the terminal as well.

Comment: Are you using `startx` as mentioned in that solution you linked to? If so, do you see any output on the terminal you ran `startx` from (error messages)?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in boot menu run a `memtest`, which is the second to last option of the boot menu. A `memtest` will check whether your machine is good for the backtrack release.

Then boot your system on `backtrack forensics` mode and check whether you are able to run everything properly.

Comment: Later after a reboot or two programs seem to open fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite normal. When you click on a menu entry Gnome calls the Exec= field defined in the dot application file, if that thing doesn't exist / can't be run, you will get nothing.

Does it apply to all menu entries? Can you launch gnome-terminal by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gnome-terminal` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?